# What does component prop in Grid layout do?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I was looking at [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/docs/src/pages/getting-started/templates/sign-in-side/SignInSide.js) example provided by material-ui docs, and I couldn't figure out what `component={Paper}` in this line does:

```
 <Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={5} component={Paper} elevation={6} square>
```

I ran this example locally, and after removing `component={Paper}` from the code I didn't see any visual changes on the web page.
The only thing I found in docs regarding this prop is:

> The component used for the root node. Either a string to use a HTML element or a component.

However, I'm struggling to understand what that means. I'd appreciate if someone could explain in simple words what that prop does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't change visually unless the root node applies additional styling to the child nodes. If you change the HTML element that gets rendered by the given `component` to something other than a `div` it might make more sense for you to understand.

For example, if I have this component I want to use as the root node:

```
const GridRoot = (props) => (
  <section>{props.children}</section>
)
```

And then render the grid like the example:

```
<Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={5} component={GridRoot} elevation={6} square>
```

The result would be that the `Grid` renders as a `<section />` rather than the default `<div />`.

Comment: So In this case I set current Grid to be of type Paper and I can add paper props, is this a correct assumption?

Comment: From the source: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Grid/Grid.js#L248 it appears that is the case it will pass additional props as `{...other}` to the given `component`